# Lager got warmed when doing secondary fermentation

Tags: lager, bottle

I'm brewing lager for the first time. Primary fermentation is completed in 2 weeks without anything negative under 8-10 Celcius. But after putting it to the secondary fermenter it seems my fridge has broken when I was away. I think the temp was around-23-25 C after fridge broke down. Perhaps it stayed like this around 2 weeks. Should I pour it to toilet? Or should I bottle it?
Thanks for responses.

Comment: Have you tastes it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine.  The results are really to lager strain dependent.  That said, I have made several lagers that were great and ready to drink without a true lager phase.  (Not to say they didn't get better as things went alone in the kegorator.)

You should really let your palate be your guide.  If it tastes great but the process didn't go along according to some "ideal" methodology...who cares?!

Comment: The yeast I used was Fermentis W34/70 (weihenstephaner yeast).

Comment: *'You should really let your palate be your guide'* Probably the best single piece of advice that any new brewer could heed. Forget what the instructions say, get a hydrometer, and taste the beer.

Comment: Lagers need a couple days at or above 68F anyways (diacetyl rest)

Comment: as long as its not infected, it will be good or eventually get good with time

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, temperature-related off-flavors in beer get produced in the first three or four days of fermentation. It is fairly common for homebrewers to ramp up the temperatures of lagers to 22C or so after the first week or two of fermentation to reduce diacetyl, and to speed the remainder of fermentation.

The bottom line is, never dump a beer based on what you think MIGHT happen, until you try it for yourself. Homebrew forums often make it seem like any error will be the end of the world, but beer is very forgiving.